# Reading RGB images with an ImageReader

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to use an `ImageReader` to get RGB images from the camera. I'm using the Camera2 API from Android 5.0 "L" on a Nexus 5 running the developer preview. Note that I am *not* asking how to convert YUV into RGB - I'm trying to get RGB directly from `ImageReader`. For anyone wanting to know how to convert YUV to RGB, feel free to consult another question, e.g. [Convert Android camera2 api YUV_420_888 to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510928/convert-android-camera2-api-yuv-420-888-to-rgb).

I already have a `SurfaceView` configured for RGB images which is working fine, and I believe that the camera hardware produces RGB data (because all the tone mapping and color gain settings on Android are specified to operate on RGB channels).

I can obtain YUV_420_888 images from ImageReader by creating the ImageReader this way:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(W, H, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 4);
```

and then converting the YUV images to RGB. However, this is introducing both an unwanted quantization error (since my application requires RGB images), and unnecessary processing time.

However, when I try creating the image reader this way:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(W, H, PixelFormat.RGB_888, 4);
```

the image capture fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The producer output buffer format 0x22 doesn't match the ImageReader's configured buffer format 0x3.
        at android.media.ImageReader.nativeImageSetup(Native Method)
        at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextSurfaceImage(ImageReader.java:293)
        at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:339)
        at android.media.ImageReader.acquireLatestImage(ImageReader.java:243)
        at <my code...>
```

I'm confused on two fronts. First, the output format mentioned, 0x22, is not in either PixelFormat or ImageFormat. It seems to be some sort of undocumented raw mode, but I can't use `ImageReader.newInstance(W, H, 0x22, 4)` to capture it (I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid format specified 34`). I would love to capture in the raw format but I can't convince ImageFormat to accept it (and the other raw format `ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR` is incredibly slow for some reason).

Second, the `SurfaceView` is already happily consuming `RGB_888` images (as far as I can tell), and putting them directly on the screen. So why isn't `ImageReader` not accepting RGB images properly? What did I do wrong?

Comment: The camera output is always YUV.  The conversion to RGB is generally performed by the GL driver, which is receiving the data as an external texture.  The point of ImageReader is to provide your app with the relatively raw camera data, without doing a conversion, so RGB is not an option.

Comment: @fadden actually the camera output is not always YUV, you can change the output format in the camera parameters, but every camera support the YUV color format (NV12), only some devices support RGB.

Comment: You should use renderscript for this type of conversion.

Answer (score -1):

> The error exception is because of [`PixelFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat) that isn't the same as [`ImageFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat).

[`PixelFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat) is equivalent to [`ImageFormat.RGB_565`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat) not the one you used [`ImageFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat).

You have to use [`ImageFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat) instead of [`PixelFormat.RGB_888`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat) like this:

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(W, H, ImageFormat.RGB_565, 4);
```

This allows to capture **RGB** from camera using [`ImageReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader).

Comment: I don’t think I follow. There is no RGB_888 in ImageFormat. I don’t want RGB_565 as it’s a 16-bit image format which loses a lot of precision (I only lose ~1.5 bits in YUV-RGB conversion, but I’d lose 16 bits in RGB565).