# Most Efficient way to send Image in YUV_420_888 from Android to JNI in OpenCV Mat

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface, android

I have an android application where I want to run some `OpenCV` image processing on live images from android `Camera2` API. Currently, If I don't do any processing, I am able to receive images in `OnImageAvailble` function at 30 fps for a regular `1280x720` frame.

Now as a dirty hack I am requesting Images from *ImageReader* in JPEG format and then passing the Bitmap to `jni` which brings down the performance a lot.

What's the most efficient way to pass the YUV frame to `jni` in `cv Mat` object. Also, I want to convert this frame to `RGB` for further processing. Should I change the format on Java side or should I pass the `Mat` object to `jni` and convert the colorspace there only.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510928/convert-android-camera2-api-yuv-420-888-to-rgb. Choose the answer you prefer.

Comment: have you looked at using [javaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) instead.

Comment: You can use Utils.bitmapToMat function to convert you bitmap to OpenCV Mat on Java size directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you do in C++ is much faster than the Java equivalent for obvious reasons, including YUV to RGB transformations (even if the Java implementation relies on compiled libraries).

You can directly pass a pointer from your existing Mat in java directly to C++ through JNI. Supposing I want to do Canny() using C++ and JNI, and I have a JNI function defined like this:

```
// In Java
public static native boolean nativeCanny(long iAddr);
```

Notice the **long iAddr** parameter, that's a direct pointer to my Mat in Java. You invoke it like this:

```
// In Java
nativeCanny(myImage.getNativeObjAddr());
```

The implementation of this function in C++ would receive this pointer in a similar way to this (replace long with jlong if this doesn't work):

```
// In C++
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
VeryLongName_nativeCanny(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, long iAddr) {
    cv::Mat* img = (cv::Mat*) iAddr;
    cv::Canny(*img, *img, 80, 100, 3);
    return true;
}
```

And whatever I did to the *img* Mat, happens in the java *myImage* Mat as well, after all it's a pointer so we never made a copy.

As far as I know, that's as fast as it gets.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe helpful to you: Since we do a lot of image processing we wrote a library for that purpose in our company. It's not written in C but it's quite performant.
After the conversion, you can simply pass the Mat pointer down to your C code via JNI.

It converts YUVs (Standard Android Camera Format YUV_420_888) to RGB Mats. In addition, it also allows efficient clipping of the YUV before the conversion (important for very big images, otherwise you would need to convert the whole image, and clip afterward which is expensive). Usage is very simple:

```
Mat mat = Yuv.toMat(image)
```

https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/yuvToMat