# How to produce YUVI420 frame to SurfaceTexture in similar manner like camera produces frames to SurfaceTexture?

Tags: android, opengl-es, yuv

I am able render `YUVI420` frame on `GLSurfaceView` using openGL but my requirement is to render frame on `SurfaceTexture`.
Basically I want to produce frame to `SurfaceTexture` not like render to `TextureView` etc., I have YUV data stream coming from WebRTC, and I want this stream to be in `SurfaceTexture` so that later I can access it in `EXTERNAL_TEXTURE_OES` at consumer level. 
I could not found any source about producing frames on SurfaceTexture. Is it possible to produce YUV frames to SurfaceTexure?

Answer (score -2):

You can convert the YUVI420 frames into a byteArray, draw it on a canvas and put it on the TextureView

```
val canvas: Canvas = textureView.lockCanvas()
canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 200f, 100f, Paint())
textureView.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
```

Comment: ```sourceBitmap``` is YUVI420 or RGB frame ? will it be available to consumer of SurfaceTexture ?

Comment: The sourceBitmap is YUVI420 but it can be converted at any time. I have found this question/answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510928/convert-android-camera2-api-yuv-420-888-to-rgb

Comment: Hey I know how to convert to RGB just go trough the documentation of SurfaceTexture. SurfaceTexture uses ```EXTERNAL_TEXTURE_OES``` which uses YUV format. Conversion to RGB is slow operation & this is not the answer to this problem see [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture?authuser=1). TextureView I know how to render YUV as well Bitmap using EGL Context.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear in the initial Question. There was only a requirement to ignore OpenGL for conversion.
But you're right, my conclusion doesn't fit that additional requirement.