# CameraX + OpenCV Image Analysis

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv, image-processing, android-camerax

I want to draw a rectangle with opencv from the image acquired by camerax and display it in imageview.

The top of the attached image is Image View and the bottom is Preview View.

[ImageView Noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfdGo.jpg)

[ImageView Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayGRT.jpg)

An image with noise or a completely black image is output.

I suspect there is a problem with the process of converting ImageProxy to Mat or Bitmap.

```
class MyImageAnalyzer(previewview:PreviewView,imageview:ImageView) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
var previewView:PreviewView = previewview
var imageView:ImageView = imageview

override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
    /* Create cv::mat(RGB888) from image(NV21) */
    val matOrg = getMatFromImage(image)

    /* Fix image rotation (it looks image in PreviewView is automatically fixed by CameraX???) */
    val mat = fixMatRotation(matOrg)

    /* Do some image processing */
    val matOutput = Mat(mat.rows(), mat.cols(), mat.type())

    /* Draw something for test */
    Imgproc.rectangle(
        matOutput,
        Rect(10, 10, 100, 100),
        Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    )

    /* Convert cv::mat to bitmap for drawing */
    val bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(matOutput.cols(), matOutput.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(matOutput, bitmap)

    /* Display the result onto ImageView */
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }

    /* Close the image otherwise, this function is not called next time */
    image.close()
}

private fun getMatFromImage(image: ImageProxy): Mat {
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510928/convert-android-camera2-api-yuv-420-888-to-rgb */
    val yBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
    val uBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer
    val vBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer
    val ySize: Int = yBuffer.remaining()
    val uSize: Int = uBuffer.remaining()
    val vSize: Int = vBuffer.remaining()
    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)
    val yuv = Mat(image.height + image.height / 2, image.width, CvType.CV_8UC1)
    yuv.put(0, 0, nv21)
    val mat = Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(yuv, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21, 3)
    return mat
}

private fun fixMatRotation(matOrg: Mat): Mat {
    val mat: Mat
    when (previewView.display.rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> {
            mat = Mat(matOrg.cols(), matOrg.rows(), matOrg.type())
            Core.transpose(matOrg, mat)
            Core.flip(mat, mat, 1)
        }
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> mat = matOrg
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> {
            mat = matOrg
            Core.flip(mat, mat, -1)
        }
        else -> {
            mat = Mat(matOrg.cols(), matOrg.rows(), matOrg.type())
            Core.transpose(matOrg, mat)
            Core.flip(mat, mat, 1)
        }
    }
    return mat
}
```

}

I hope the processed image is displayed smoothly on the ImageView

Comment: Please don't use links. A link may become broken, making the question useless for future users. Add the image to the question by using the Image option from the toolbar.

Comment: does this issue _require_ opencv to be demonstrated? you describe what sounds like _acquisition_ issues, yet you don't use OpenCV for acquisition. [mre] please. also, if you haven't, please take the [tour] and review [ask]

Comment: I am using a toolbar button to insert the image.

I am getting the image with CameraX, but there is no problem in acquiring the image, and there seems to be a problem in the process of converting to mat or bitmap.